# In which file Tomcat Java Memory options are saved

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, configuration

I want to change memory configuration of Tomcat. I know it can be done at
`Start > Apache Tomcat > Configure Tomcat > Java Tab]` as can be seen below

[image: here]

and specifying options like

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
```

there.

However this program group is created if I install Tomcat from an executable. I have installed Tomcat by simply extracting the zip which does not create Program group. So now where can I specify this information

Comment: Look in the base directory, there must be a catalina-env.bat in there IIRC

Comment: catalina.bat does not store any such options, and am not still finding where these parameters is specified, are these options specified in registry?

Comment: I said catalina-_env_.bat

Comment: There exists no such file in Tomcat installation.

Comment: Well, my memory is failing then -- but you certainly have a file somewhere which allows you to set your environment. Look at the catalina.bat script, this file must be sourced somewhere

Comment: ohkay found it. Its setenv.bat. By default its not present. Added in answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ohkay while digging inside Tomcat I found some information in one of its [txt files (point 3.4)](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) and [online](http://wiki.razuna.com/display/ecp/Adjusting+Memory+Settings+for+Tomcat):

Apart from `CATALINA_HOME` (which is set to `apache-tomcat-x.x.x` directory, for e.g. `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.41`) and `CATALINA_BASE` (optional, defaults to `CATALINA_HOME`), all environment variables can
be specified in the `setenv` script. The script is placed either into
`CATALINA_BASE/bin` or into `CATALINA_HOME/bin` directory and is named
`setenv.bat` (on Windows) or setenv.sh (on *nix). The file has to be
readable.

By default the `setenv` script file is absent. If the script file is present
both in `CATALINA_BASE` and in `CATALINA_HOME`, the one in `CATALINA_BASE` is
preferred.

For example, to configure the `JRE_HOME` and `CATALINA_PID` variables you can
create the following script file:

On Windows, `%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat`:

```
set "JRE_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre6"
exit /b 0
```

On *nix, $CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh:

```
JRE_HOME=/usr/java/latest
CATALINA_PID="$CATALINA_BASE/tomcat.pid"
```

To set Java options for memory allocation for web app, add something like following (as per memory requirements of your application) to the same file

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
```

The `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` variables cannot be configured in the
`setenv` script, because they are used to locate that file.

All the environment variables described here and the `setenv` script are
used only if you use the standard scripts to launch Tomcat. For example, if
you have installed Tomcat as a service on Windows, the service wrapper
launches Java directly and does not use the script files.

Comment: The same text file says: "Note: Do not use JAVA_OPTS to specify memory limits. You do not need much memory for a small process that is used to stop Tomcat. Those settings belong to CATALINA_OPTS.". Probably better to specify it in CATALINA_OPTS.

Answer (score 7):

With regards to the question of where Tomcat's memory options are saved when using the service version, on my machine at least they can be found in the Windows Registry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat-6\Parameters\Java
```

Initial memory and Maximum memory are recorded against the JvmMs and JvmMx values, while the options text is recorded against the Options value.

The Tomcat-6 portion of the address on mine is, I believe, based on the identifier I gave to the service (i.e. within the service manager Tomcat is named "Apache Tomcat 6.0 Tomcat-6"), and you may not need to go through Wow6432Node depending on whether you're using 32-bit or 64-bit Tomcat.

I'm assuming here that they haven't made any dramatic changes in where this information is stored in versions of Tomcat more recent than Tomcat 6.